# JAVA : how to reduce code size, when using lambda to process array's items

Tags: java, arrays, lambda

I must sort each item in the array, in alphabatic order

in :
**[bcdef, dbaqc, abcde, omadd, bbbbb]**
out :
**[bcdef, abcdq, abcde, addmo, bbbbb]**

I wrote the code below but i feel it verbose(long).

Could you please tell me an other way, with shorter code ?

Thanks.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static java.lang.String.copyValueOf;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] stringsArray = { "bcdef", "dbaqc", "abcde", "omadd", "bbbbb"};

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stringsArray));

        List<String> list = Arrays.stream(stringsArray).map((String s)->{
            char[] charArray = s.toCharArray();
            Arrays.sort(charArray);
            return copyValueOf(charArray);
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(list);
        stringsArray = Arrays.copyOf(arrayList.toArray(),arrayList.size(),String[].class);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stringsArray));
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you expect "bcdef" to be ordered before "abcdq"?

Comment: If the code works but you want it optimised for brevity, post it to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: `I must sort each item in the array, in alphabatic order` should be read as "I must sort the characters in alphabetic order of each string from a string array", right ?

Comment: @jsheeran, if brevity is _really_ important, try [codegolf.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to sort characters within each element, not the whole array.

You could simplify by having separate `map()` (and `peek()` since `Arrays.sort()` method is not returning a value) steps. You could also skip redundant `List` by collecting directly to a `String` array.

```
String[] sorted = Arrays.stream(stringsArray)
    .map(String::toCharArray)
    .peek(Arrays::sort)
    .map(String::new)
    .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: While this solution works, please note that `peek` should not be used to modify the state of the elements of the stream. According to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek(java.util.function.Consumer)) it should be used mainly for debugging (peeking into the stream). Also the consumer parameter should be a "non-interfering action to perform on the elements".

Answer (score 5):

If you want to modify the original array in-place, then you can rely on `Arrays.asList()`, which creates a `List` wrapper around the array:

```
Arrays.asList(stringsArray)
        .replaceAll(s -> {
            char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
            Arrays.sort(chars);
            return new String(chars);
        });

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stringsArray));
```

`Arrays.asList()` is really just a view on the original array. Any change to the returned list will actually be done on the array, and vice-versa. This is also why you cannot add/remove elements on the returned list.